# Proving a simple claim regarding irrational numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, irrational-numbers

I am trying to prove the following claim:
Let $ n \in \Bbb N$ and let $p$ be a prime number for which $p \nmid n$.
Prove that $\sqrt {pn} \notin \Bbb Q$ .
I was able to prove it by assuming by contradiction that $\sqrt {pn} \in \Bbb Q$ so there exists $a,b \in \Bbb Z$ such that$ \sqrt { pn}=\frac ab$ . after a few steps I get to the fact that $n=\frac{a^2}{pb^2}$. Obviously this shows that $n \notin \Bbb Z$, which is a contradiction to the fact that $n \in \Bbb N$. The problem is I am having isuues writing the formal proof that $n \notin \Bbb Z$.
Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: Seems that you have found a proof. What else do you want ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear, The proof using contradiction is elegant in this case and can you elaborate what are issues?

Comment: Yes, the issue is that I am not sure how to conclude in a formal mathematical way that $n \notin Z$

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me how $n=\frac{a^2}{p b^2}$ implies that $n$ is not an integer. Say for example that $b=1$ and $a=p$.

Let's go back to the equation $pn=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$. If we assume that $a$ and $b$ are coprime (which we can) then we have that $b=1$. So $pn=a^2$. Now consider the prime decomposition of $pn$ and of $a^2$, which must be equal. What is the power of $p$ on this decomposition? Can you derive a contradiction from this?

It is the same idea that appears on the standard proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: I can conclude from it that $\sqrt {pn}=\sqrt p \sqrt n=a$ I can also conclude that $\sqrt p$ is irrational. so in order that a will be rational $\sqrt n$ must be irrational. How can I conclude from the fact that p does not divide n that a is not integer? that way will lead me to a contradiction

Comment: Just think of the prime decompositions. The prime decomposition of $pn$ only contains $p$ once, because $p$ does not divide $n$. On the other hand, the prime decomposition of $a^2$ will satisfy that all the primes have even exponents. For example, if $a=12=3\cdot 2^2$, then we have that $a^2 = 3^2 2^4$.